# CakePHP: validation( ) fails

Tags: validation, cakephp, phpunit

My validation fails, so my test for this message throws an `ValidationException` every time.
"Not all fields are filled out correct". Why? Analoguosly, it works for users (another method).

**MODEL:**

```
public $validate = array(
    'name' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Name can not be empty',
        ),
        'unique' => array(
            'rule' => 'isUnique',
            'message' => 'This name is already used.',
        ),
    ),
    'address' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Address can not be empty',
        ),
```

...

```
public function saveNewInstitution($institutionData, $userId) {
    $institutionData[$this->alias]['is_active'] = 1;
    $institutionData[$this->alias]['user_id'] = $userId;
    $this->create();
    $this->set($institutionData);
    if ($this->validates()) {
        return $this->save();
    } else {
        throw new ValidationException('Not all fields are filled out correct');
    }
}
```

**TESTclass:**

```
public function testSaveNewInstitution() {
    $data = array(
        'Institution' => array(
            'name' => 'Spitex Staufen',
            'address' => 'Hauptweg 4',
            'postcode' => '1234',
            'city' => 'huuh',
            'phone_number' => '123 456 78 90',
            'email' => 'staufen@spitex.huuh',
            'comment' => '',
            'institution_type_id' => 5
            ));
    $expected = array(
        'Institution' => array(
            'id' => 2,
            'name' => 'Spitex Staufen',
            'address' => 'Hauptweg 4',
            'postcode' => '1234',
            'city' => 'huuh',
            'phone_number' => '123 456 78 90',
            'email' => 'staufen@spitex.huuh',
            'comment' => '',
            'is_active' => TRUE,
            'user_id' => 2,
            'institution_type_id' => 5
            ));

    $result = $this->Institution->saveNewInstitution($data, 2);
    $this->assertEqual($result, $expected);
}
```

and all the Exceptionhandling methods like this:

```
public function testSaveNewInstitutionExceptionName() {
    $this->setExpectedException('ValidationException');
    $this->Institution->saveNewInstitution($this->__nameEmpty, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i got it really - is your Testclass failing or is the saveNewInstitution() function making you troubles? Did you try to check if the saveNewInstitution() is working correct by hand - put some data in a form an pass it to your function?

Maybe it's just a small thing and you have an entry with id=2 in your database an you got a duplicate key exception overwritten by your own exception method testSaveNewInstitutionExceptionName().